# unable to use ahoy gem for usage tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ahoy

I'm trying to use ahoy_matey gem in development env. i.e. Windows7 64 bit and rails 4.0.9 by following the doc at https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.

I would like to use this gem to track user visits and ip addresses in particular and then restrict the number of sign-in's per IP address. I've followed the readme file but unable to see records in visits table in my pg db.

Below are the steps I've followed so far -

```
gem 'ahoy_matey' #included in gem file and ran bundle install
//= require ahoy # included this line in application.js file
rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record -d postgresql 
rake db:migrate 
gem 'fluent-logger' #ran bundle install after including this line in gem file
```

The below command generated an error- *Could not find generator ahoy:stores:fluentd.*

```
rails generate ahoy:stores:fluentd
```

I've tried including below script in /layout/application.html.erb and other pages as well inside script tags without success.

```
ahoy.trackAll();
```

included the below in my sign in method in session controller

```
 ahoy.authenticate(user)
```

Included the below in my index method of landing page without success.
    ahoy.track "Viewed Landing", title: "Landing page viewed"

The only thing that has worked so far is below code which I've added in my application controller and it is populating my ahoy_events table.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
after_filter :track_action

def track_action
ahoy.track "Processed #{controller_name}##{action_name}", request.filtered_parameters
end
```

I've also restarted my rails webserver (I'm using thin in dev and puma in prod).

Could you please let me know what I'm missing here. What do I need to do differently with my ahoy setup to enable it to start writing records to the "visits table" in my pg database.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Hi, Just another update.. I've now noticed that visits table does gets populated if i access website from IE Or Firefox. I'm unable to see any record if i access it from chrome browser. Any idea why this would be the case??

Answer (score 0):

have you try to find some js code that may not be compliant with browsers that doesn't appear in visits table ?

edit :

I detail my idea : if you have any js code not compliant that make browser didn't get 200 http success and then the page loading fail, if your ahoy call is after that, browser didn't execute it